Authentication header not reaching server in React & NodeJS app after deploying on server
I have an app with front end built in React and backend with NodeJS. My app is working fine when I run locally on my computer using local hosts. However, when I deployed my app on render.com, I'm facing an issue with my authentication header.
I login to app successfully, but after that to access APIs I have to use JWT. I receive the JWT after login and include it in my request to later APIs, but my server do not receive the authentication header. Following snapshot shows the problem:

Request sent from chrome includes authorization header.


However, on server side following header is received:

Response received from server shows there was no header in request.


I've attached both screenshots from chrome developer options. Also below you can see snapshot for console for header received on server:

Reached verifyToken with token: {"host":"nearusnewadminserver.onrender.com","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36","accept":"/","accept-encoding":"gzip, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9,ur-PK;q=0.8,ur;q=0.7,fa-IR;q=0.6,fa;q=0.5,ar-AE;q=0.4,ar;q=0.3","access-control-request-headers":"authorization","access-control-request-method":"GET","cdn-loop":"cloudflare; loops=1; subreqs=1","cf-connecting-ip":"185.67.127.180","cf-ew-via":"15","cf-ipcountry":"GB","cf-ray":"8be10f90528977a5-LHR","cf-visitor":"{"scheme":"https"}","cf-worker":"onrender.com","origin":"http://localhost:8000","priority":"u=1, i","referer":"http://localhost:8000/","render-proxy-ttl":"4","rndr-id":"d77239b2-95cc-481b","sec-fetch-dest":"empty","sec-fetch-mode":"cors","sec-fetch-site":"cross-site","true-client-ip":"185.67.127.180","x-forwarded-for":"185.67.127.180, 10.222.42.14, 10.223.245.2","x-forwarded-proto":"https","x-request-start":"1725485217438628"}

Note that I had to add following middleware to my backend as my front end host and backend host are different on render.com: (In below snapshot I used my dev-server host url as I'm testing with it to make sure header is included.
function accessControl(req,res,next){
    console.log(`Reached access control allow part`);
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8000");
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
    );
    next();
}

module.exports = {
    accessControl
}

I have searched many forums but couldn't find the solution. It is also worth noting that when I send the same request with Postman it works fine.

It looks like you have a CORS error in the browser console because the options request failed.
Please  check how it's implemented in cors lib
https://github.com/expressjs/cors/blob/master/lib/index.js#L159
Firstly you need to handle Options request and send successful response. You forgot about Access-Control-Allow-Methods.
I recommend you to use this lib instead of yours uncompleted solution https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors
Example:
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
 
app.use(cors({
  origin: ["http://localhost:8000"],
}))
 
app.get('/countries', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json(['US']);
})
 
app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('server listening')
})

Provide the code how you are using this accessControl middleware.
For this to work, it should look like this:
app.get('/countries', accessControl, (req, res) => {
  res.json(['US']);
});

or like this:
app.use(accessControl)

app.get('/countries', (req, res) => {
  res.json(['US']);
});


Thanks. It was indeed CORS error. My middleware had problem and issue was solved by using your recommended CORS library. This is my first deployment and didn't know much about CORS. Thanks for your quick and detailed response.
